# How to use scala.None from Java code

Tags: java, scala, singleton, scala-java-interop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing scala.None from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059511/accessing-scala-none-from-java)

In Java you can create an instance of `Some` using the constructor, i.e. `new Some(value)`, but `None` has no partner class.  How do you pass `None` to a Scala function from Java?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think this ugly bit will work: `scala.None$.MODULE$`

There is no need for a new instance since one None is as good as another...

Comment: "one None is as good as another". A tagline for the scala language?

Answer (score 59):

The `scala.None$.MODULE$` thing doesn't always typecheck, for example this doesn't compile:

```
scala.Option<String> x = scala.None$.MODULE$;
```

because javac doesn't know about Scala's declaration-site variance, so you get:

```
J.java:3: incompatible types
found   : scala.None$
required: scala.Option<java.lang.String>
    scala.Option<String> x = scala.None$.MODULE$ ;
```

This does compile, though:

```
scala.Option<String> x = scala.Option.apply(null);
```

so that's a different way to get a None that is usable in more situations.

Comment: I even had to write "scala.Option.apply((String) null)" to make the compiler happy.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, while scala.None$.MODULE$ produced type errors.

Answer (score 11):

You can access the singleton None instance from java using:

```
scala.None$.MODULE$
```

Answer (score 3):

I've found this this generic function to be the most robust. You need to supply the type parameter, but the cast only appears once, which is nice. Some of the other solutions will not work in various scenarios, as your Java compiler may inform you.

```java
import scala.None$;
import scala.Option;

public class ScalaLang {

    public static <T> Option<T> none() {
        return (Option<T>) None$.MODULE$;
    }
}

public class ExampleUsage {
    static {
        //for example, with java.lang.Long
        ScalaLang.<Long>none();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is one of the cleaner options around this. It clearly feels that calling Scala code from Java is less than optimal sometimes. :(

Answer (score 1):

Faced with this stinkfest, my usual modus operandi is:

Scala:

```
object SomeScalaObject {
  def it = this
}
```

Java:

```
doStuff(SomeScalaObject.it());
```