# Accessing scala.None from Java

Tags: java, scala, singleton, scala-java-interop, option-type

How can you access `scala.None` from Java?

The last line causes the compiler to die with "type scala.None does not take parameters".

```
import scala.Option;
import scala.Some;
import scala.None;
final Option<String> object1 = new Some<String>("Hi there");
final Option<String> object2 = new None<String>();
```

This fails with "cannot find symbol constructor None()":

```
final Option<String> object2 = new None();
```

This fails with "cannot find symbol variable None":

```
final Option<String> object2 = None;
```

In 2007 this used to work, but then Scala changed. The Java compiler gives `error: incompatible types`:

```
final Option<String> object2 = scala.None$.MODULE$;
```

Comment: By the way... `scala.None$.MODULE$` should still work. What problem did you have with it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use scala.None from Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997433/how-to-use-scala-none-from-java-code)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This might work:

```
final scala.Option<String> x = scala.Option.apply(null);
```

> def apply [A] (x: A): Option[A]
>    An Option factory which creates
>   Some(x) if the argument is not null, and None if it is null.

Comment: just like java: ugly but effective

Comment: What is your Scala version? In Scala 2.11, it does not work.

Comment: @AlvaroAgea checked on scala v2.11.7, works like a charm. Can you elaborate how exactly it doesn't work?

Answer (score 18):

Using Scala 2.10.2 (not sure at what version when this came in):

```
final Option<String> none = Option.empty();
```

Answer (score 9):

Not to put too fine a point on it, but one shouldn't rely on static forwarders, as they might not get generated under certain circumstances. For instance, `Some` doesn't have static forwarders for its object companion.

The current way of accessing methods on an object companion is this:

```
final scala.Option<String> x = scala.Option$.MODULE$.apply(null);
```

`Option$` is the class for the object companion of `Option`. `MODULE$` is a final public static field that contains the sole instance of `Option$` (in other words, the object companion).

Answer (score 1):

You can import

```
import scala.compat.java8.OptionConverters;
```

And then:

```
OptionConverters.<YourType>toScala(Optional.empty())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following (I tested it out and it works fine for me with Scala 2.9.1 and Java 1.6):

```
 final Option<String> obj1 = Some.apply(null) // This will give you a None;
 System.out.println(obj1.getClass()); // will print "class scala.None$

 final Option<String> obj2 = Some.apply("Something");
 System.out.println(obj2.getClass()); //will print "class scala.Some
```

Comment: I didn't see the answer @om-nom-nom posted when I wrote this but I think that should work as well.

Comment: `Some(null)` is `Some(null)`, not `None`.

Comment: That's what I expected, because it would make sense and that's what happens when I try that through the Scala interpreter. But when I try the code I posted above in a java file and run that I get obj2.getClass() giving me None$. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: When I do this through Java it looks like because Some extends Option it calls Option's factory apply method which in turn returns None if the argument to apply is null.

Comment: Oh, wow, that is something I had never imagined! Ok, here's the deal: Java has static inheritance, Scala doesn't. The object `Some` doesn't, and can't, extend the object `Option`, but Scala creates static forwarders from the class to the object unless some conflict shows up. The correct way to invoke `apply' is to do it on `scala.Some$.MODULE$` (or `Option$`, etc). It just happens that `Option` has static forwarders but `Some` doesn't, so _Java's_ static inheritance comes into play. So weird.

Comment: Glad you were able to shed some light on this. I'm just getting started with Scala so I don't have knowledge of the language internals yet but I'm working on it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Scala version 2.11.4 the only thing that worked out in my case, was

```
Option<String> maybeAmount = (amount != MISSING_STOCKAMOUNT) 
? Some.apply(amount+"") : Option.<String>apply(null); // can you feel the pain??
```

Update: a day later...

```
Option.apply(null);
```

without the type parameter does work too, as it should. For some reason I couldn't get Intellij to compile the code on my first attempt. I had to pass the secondary type parameter. Now it compiles, just don't ask

Comment: Yes, that seems painful. What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Oracle JDK 1.8.0_65