# Scala Option.orElse in Java

Tags: java, scala

Same idea as my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059511/accessing-scala-none-from-java), just a little more advanced. I want to write the following Scala code in Java:

```
Option(System.getProperty("not.present")).orElse(Some("default")).get
```

I tried this:

```
    final Function0<Option<String>> elseOption = new Function0<Option<String>>() { 
        @Override public Option<String> apply() { 
            return new Some<String>("default"); 
        }
    };

    final Option<String> notPresent =
        new Some<String>(System.getProperty("not.present")).
        orElse(elseOption).get();
```

But I get:

```
<anonymous OptionDemo$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method apply$mcD$sp() in scala.Function0
[error]       orElse(new Function0<Option<String>>() {
```

Comment: By the way: `Option(System.getProperty("x")) getOrElse "default"` is more concise and clear than what you have

Comment: +1 on oxbow_lakes, try to always avoid doing ".get"

Comment: Good catch! I now have:
Option(System.getProperty("not.present")).getOrElse("default")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `AbstractFunction0` instead of `Function0`. That should give you the trait-provided methods.

Comment: The following always returns null in Java, although the equivalent Scala works fine.

    final AbstractFunction0<String> elseOption = new AbstractFunction0<String>() { 
     @Override public String apply() { 
      return "default"; 
  }
 };
    
    final String notPresent =
      (new Some<String>(System.getProperty("not.present"))).getOrElse(elseOption);
      

Sorry, just cannot get code formatting to work in a comment.

Comment: @MikeSlinn Make another question about it. They don't charge per question here, y'know? :-)

Comment: @MikeSlinn but, basically, because you used `Some`, it will *always* return the content of `Some`. It is `Option`, not `Some`, that turns nulls into `None`.