# How to investigate objects/types/etc. from Scala REPL?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop, exploratory

I've been working with Scala for a while now and have written a 10,000+ line program with it, but I'm still confused by some of the inner workings. I came to Scala from Python after already having intimate familiarity with Java, C and Lisp, but even so it's been slow going, and a huge problem is the frustrating difficulty I've often found when trying to investigate the inner workings of objects/types/classes/etc. using the Scala REPL as compared with Python. In Python you can investigate any object `foo` (type, object in a global variable, built-in function, etc.) using `foo` to see what the thing evaluates to, `type(foo)` to show its type, `dir(foo)` to tell you the methods you can call on it, and `help(foo)` to get the built-in documentation.  You can even do things like `help("re")` to find out the documentation on the package named `re` (which holds regular-expression objects and methods), even though there isn't an object associated with it.

In Scala, you can try and read the documentation online, go look up the source code to the library, etc., but this can often be very difficult for things where you don't know where or even what they are (and it's often a big chunk to bite off, given the voluminous type hierarchy) -- stuff is floating around in various places (package `scala`, `Predef`, various implicit conversions, symbols like `::` that are nearly impossible to Google). The REPL should be the way to explore directly, but in reality, things are far more mysterious.  Say that I've seen a reference to `foo` somewhere, but I have no idea what it is.  There's apparently no such thing as a "guide to systematically investigating Scala thingies with the REPL", but the following is what I've pieced together after a great deal of trial and error:

1. If `foo` is a value (which presumably includes things stored in variables plus companion objects and other Scala `object`s), you can evaluate `foo` directly.  This ought to tell you the type and value of the result.  Sometimes the result is helpful, sometimes not.
2. If `foo` is a value, you can use `:type foo` to get its type. (Not necessarily enlightening.) If you use this on a function call, you get the type of the return value, without calling the function.
3. If `foo` is a value, you can use `foo.getClass` to get its class. (Often more enlightening than the previous, but how does an object's class differ from its type?)
4. For a class `foo`, you can use `classOf[foo]`, although it's not obvious what the result means.
5. Theoretically, you can use `:javap foo` to disassemble a class -- which should be the most useful of all, but fails entirely and uniformly for me.
6. Sometimes you have to piece things together from error messages.

Example of failure using `:javap`:

```
scala> :javap List
Failed: Could not find class bytes for 'List'
```

Example of enlightening error message:

```
scala> assert
<console>:8: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method assert in object Predef of type (assertion: Boolean, message: => Any)Unit
and  method assert in object Predef of type (assertion: Boolean)Unit
match expected type ?
              assert
              ^
```

OK, now let's try a simple example.

```
scala> 5
res63: Int = 5

scala> :type 5
Int

scala> 5.getClass
res64: java.lang.Class[Int] = int
```

Simple enough ...

Now, let's try some real cases, where it's not so obvious:

```
scala> Predef
res65: type = scala.Predef$@3cd41115

scala> :type Predef
type

scala> Predef.getClass
res66: java.lang.Class[_ <: object Predef] = class scala.Predef$
```

What does this mean?  Why is the type of `Predef` simply `type`, whereas the class is `scala.Predef$`? I gather that the $ is the way that companion objects are shoehorned into Java ...  but Scala docs on Google tell me that `Predef` is `object Predef extends LowPriorityImplicits` -- how can I deduce this from the REPL?  And how can I look into what's in it?

OK, let's try another confusing thing:

```
scala> `::`
res77: collection.immutable.::.type = ::

scala> :type `::`
collection.immutable.::.type

scala> `::`.getClass
res79: java.lang.Class[_ <: object scala.collection.immutable.::] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon$

scala> classOf[`::`]
<console>:8: error: type :: takes type parameters
              classOf[`::`]
                      ^

scala> classOf[`::`[Int]]
res81: java.lang.Class[::[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

OK, this left me hopelessly confused, and eventually I had to go read the source code to make sense of this all.

So, my questions are:

1. What's the recommended best way from the true Scala experts of using the REPL to make sense of Scala objects, classes, methods, etc., or at least investigate them as best as can be done from the REPL?
2. How do I get `:javap` working from the REPL for built-in stuff? (Shouldn't it work by default?)

Thanks for any enlightenment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You mentioned an important point which Scala lacks a bit: the documentation.

The REPL is a fantastic tool, but it is not as fantastic at it can be. There are too much missing features and features which can be improved - some of them are mentioned in your post. Scaladoc is a nice tool, too, but is far away to be perfect. Furthermore lots of code in the API is not yet or too less documented and code examples are often missing. The IDEs are full ob bugs and compared to the possibilities Java IDEs show us they look like some kindergarten toys.

Nevertheless there is a gigantic difference of Scalas current tools compared to the tools available as I started to learn Scala 2-3 years ago. At that time IDEs compiled permanently some trash in the background, the compiler crashed every few minutes and some documentation was absolutely nonexistent. Frequently I got rage attacks and wished death and corruption to Scala authors.

And now? I do not have any of these rage attacks any more. Because the tools we currently have are great although the are not perfect!

There is [docs.scala-lang.org](http://docs.scala-lang.org), which summarizes a lot of great documentation. There are Tutorials, Cheat-sheets, Glossaries, Guides and a lot of more great stuff. Another great tool was Scalex, which can find even the weirdest operator one can think of. It is Scalas [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and even though it is not yet as good as his great ideal, it is very useful.

Great improvements are coming with Scala2.10 in form of Scalas own Reflection library:

```
// needs Scala2.10M4
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => u}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe=>u}

scala> val t = u.typeOf[List[_]]
t: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = List[Any]

scala> t.declarations
res10: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(constructor List, method companion, method isEmpty, method head, method tail, method ::, method :::, method reverse_:::, method mapConserve, method ++, method +:, method toList, method take, method drop, method slice, method takeRight, method splitAt, method takeWhile, method dropWhile, method span, method reverse, method stringPrefix, method toStream, method removeDuplicates)
```

Documentation for the new Reflection library is still missing, but in progress. It allows one to use scalac in an easy way inside of the REPL:

```
scala> u reify { List(1,2,3) map (_+1) }
res14: reflect.runtime.universe.Expr[List[Int]] = Expr[List[Int]](immutable.this.List.apply(1, 2, 3).map(((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1)))(immutable.this.List.canBuildFrom))

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror=>m}

scala> val tb = m.mkToolBox()
tb: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@32f7fa37

scala> tb.parseExpr("List(1,2,3) map (_+1)")
res16: tb.u.Tree = List(1, 2, 3).map(((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1)))

scala> tb.runExpr(res16)
res18: Any = List(2, 3, 4)
```

This is even greater when we want to know how Scala code is translated internally. Formerly wen need to type `scala -Xprint:typer -e "List(1,2,3) map (_+1)"` to get the internally representation. Furthermore some small improvements found there way to the new release, for example:

```
scala> :type Predef
scala.Predef.type
```

Scaladoc will gain some [type-hierarchy graph](https://scala-webapps.epfl.ch/jenkins/view/scaladoc/job/scaladoc-diagram-nightly/ws/build/scaladoc/library/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) (click on type-hierarchy).

With Macros it is possible now, to improve error messages in a great way. There is a library called [expecty](https://github.com/pniederw/expecty), which does this:

```
// copied from GitHub page
import org.expecty.Expecty

case class Person(name: String = "Fred", age: Int = 42) {
  def say(words: String*) = words.mkString(" ")
}

val person = Person()
val expect = new Expecty()

// Passing expectations

expect {
  person.name == "Fred"
  person.age * 2 == 84
  person.say("Hi", "from", "Expecty!") == "Hi from Expecty!"
}

// Failing expectation

val word1 = "ping"
val word2 = "pong"

expect {
  person.say(word1, word2) == "pong pong"
}

/*
Output:

java.lang.AssertionError:

person.say(word1, word2) == "pong pong"
|      |   |      |      |
|      |   ping   pong   false
|      ping pong
Person(Fred,42)
*/
```

There is a tool which allows one to find libraries hosted on GitHub, called [ls.implicit.ly](http://ls.implicit.ly/).

The IDEs now have some semantic highlighting, to show if a member is a object/type/method/whatever. The semantic highlighting feature of [ScalaIDE](http://scala-ide.org/docs/helium/features/semantic-highlighting/index.html).

The javap feature of the REPL is only a call to the native javap, therefore it is not a very featue-rich tool. You have to fully qualify the name of a module:

```
scala> :javap scala.collection.immutable.List
Compiled from "List.scala"
public abstract class scala.collection.immutable.List extends scala.collection.AbstractSeq implements scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq,scala.Product,scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized{
...
```

Some time ago I have written a [summary of how Scala code is compiled to Bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350528/how-to-work-with-javap-for-scala-java-interop), which offers a lot of things to know.

And the best: This is all done in the last few months!

So, how to use all of these things inside of the REPL? Well, it is not possible ... not yet. ;)

But I can tell you that one day we will have such a REPL. A REPL which shows us documentation if we want to see it. A REPL which let us communicate with it (maybe like [lambdabot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lambdabot)). A REPL which let us do cool things we still cannot imagine. I don't know when this will be the case, but I know that a lot of stuff was done in the last years and I know even greater stuff will be done in the next years.

Comment: Thanks for a terrific write-up! I'd also mention `showRaw` that was added shortly after M4 was released (and will appear in M5 tomorrow). It lets one inspect internal structure of some reflection artifacts (including trees and types).

Comment: @EugeneBurmako: I know `universe.showRaw` which is a member of M4, do you mean another `showRaw`?

Comment: Yep, I'm talking about this one. It was significantly reworked a few days after the release of M4.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako `showRaw` was not on M4? Thank God I compile my own 2.10!

Comment: I'm going to take issue with the DOC put-down at the beginning. Nowdays, docs.scala-lang.org is full of goodies, and while there are still patches low on documentation on Scaladoc, they are seldomly treaded patches.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral: Documentation has improved a lot in the last months, that's true. Nevertheless I don't feel like it is good - I feel like it is just enough to start with. Many higher order methods are insufficient documented (like `map` or `foldLeft`) - they don't provide examples of how to use them. That's essential just for beginners lacking experience with higher-order-functions. That's why I wrote "lacks a bit" and not "lacks totally".

Comment: I would definitely love an update on your answer and on how things changed in the last three years.

Comment: I would much appreciate an update to your answer as well, since I'm still facing many of the same problems as OP and it's almost 4 years later now. Surely things must have gotten better?

Comment: @rkrzr Noticed, but I'm not motivated to write about it right now. The thing I can say is that documentation is still a problem and didn't mature as much as I hoped. There are other things possible today but that is so much work to write down...

Comment: Note: Scalex has been abandoned, marked as such on GitHub, and the domain name reverted to Yahoo.

Too bad.

Comment: Now Scalex brings you to some weird system message/bug so don't click on it

Answer (score 5):

Javap works, but you are pointing it to `scala.Predef.List`, which is a `type`, not a `class`. Point it instead to `scala.collection.immutable.List`.

Now, for the most part just entering a value and seeing what the result's type is is enough. Using `:type` can be helpful sometimes. I find that use `getClass` is a really bad way of going about it, though.

Also, you are sometimes mixing types and values. For example, here you refer to the object `::`:

```
scala> `::`.getClass res79: java.lang.Class[_ <: object
scala.collection.immutable.::] = class
scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon$
```

And here you refer to the class `::`:

```
scala> classOf[`::`[Int]] res81: java.lang.Class[::[Int]] = class
scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

Objects and classes are not the same thing, and, in fact, there's a common pattern of objects and classes by the same name, with a specific name for their relationship: companions.

Instead of `dir`, just use tab completion:

```
scala> "abc".
+                     asInstanceOf          charAt                codePointAt           codePointBefore       codePointCount
compareTo             compareToIgnoreCase   concat                contains              contentEquals         endsWith
equalsIgnoreCase      getBytes              getChars              indexOf               intern                isEmpty
isInstanceOf          lastIndexOf           length                matches               offsetByCodePoints    regionMatches
replace               replaceAll            replaceFirst          split                 startsWith            subSequence
substring             toCharArray           toLowerCase           toString              toUpperCase           trim

scala> "abc".compareTo
compareTo             compareToIgnoreCase

scala> "abc".compareTo
                             def compareTo(String): Int
```

If you enter the power mode, you'll get way more information, but that's hardly for beginners. The above shows types, methods, and method signatures. Javap will decompile stuff, though that requires you to have a good handle on bytecode.

There's other stuff in there -- be sure to look up `:help`, and see what's available.

Docs are only available through the scaladoc API. Keep it open on the browser, and use its *search* capability to quickly find classes and methods. Also, note that, as opposed to Java, you don't need to navigate through the inheritance list to get the description of the method.

And they do search perfectly fine for symbols. I suspect you haven't spent much time on scaladoc because other doc tools out there just aren't up to it. Javadoc comes to mind -- it's awful browsing through packages and classes.

If you have specific questions Stack Overflow style, use [Symbol Hound](http://symbolhound.com/) to search with symbols.

Use the [nightly](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html) Scaladocs: they'll diverge from whatever version you are using, but they'll always be the most complete. Besides, right now they are far better in many respects: you can use TAB to alternate between frames, with auto-focus on the search boxes, you can use arrows to navigate on the left frame after filtering, and ENTER to have the selected element appear on the right frame. They have the list of implicit methods, and have class diagrams.

I've made do with a far less powerful REPL, and a far poorer Scaladoc -- they do work, together. Granted, I skipped to trunk (now HEAD) just to get my hands on tab-completion.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about either Tab completion or power mode, or the different Lists. Your message also emphasizes what I said above in that there's no obvious documentation telling me about any of these things.  I do use Scaladoc a lot but IMO it's not ideal in the way that the REPL lets you directly look at what's actually present in your current Scala, not some other one. As for `::`, I'm aware there's both a type and a class but the point is that it's often not obvious which is which when you're not a Scala expert, and you shouldn't have to know this in advance when using the REPL.

Answer (score 4):

Note that [scala 2.11.8 New tab-completion in the Scala REPL](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.11.8/#new-tab-completion-in-the-scala-repl) can facilitate the type exploration/discovery.

It now includes:

- CamelCase completion:
  try:
  `(l: List[Int]).rro`<kbd>TAB</kbd>,
  it expands to:
  `(l: List[Int]).reduceRightOption`
- Find members by typing any CamelCased part of the name:
  try:
  `classOf[String].typ`<kbd>TAB</kbd>,
  to get `getAnnotationsByType`, `getComponentType` and others
- Complete bean getters without typing get:
  try:
  `(d: java.util.Date).day`<kbd>TAB</kbd>
- Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice to see the method signature:
  try:
  `List(1,2,3).part`<kbd>TAB</kbd>,
  which completes to:
  `List(1,2,3).partition`;
  press <kbd>TAB</kbd> again to display:
  `def partition(p: Int => Boolean): (List[Int], List[Int])`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass fully qualified class name to `javap`.

First take it using `classOf`:

```
scala> classOf[List[_]]
res2: java.lang.Class[List[_]] = class scala.collection.immutable.List
```

Then use `javap` (doesn't work from repl for me: ":javap unavailable on this platform.") so example is from a command line, in repl, I believe, you don't need to specify classpath:

```
d:\bin\scala\scala-2.9.1-1\lib>javap -classpath scala-library.jar "scala.collection.immutable.List"
```

But I doubt this will help you. Probably you're trying to use techniques you used to use in dynamic languages. I extremely rarely use repl in scala (while use it often in javascript). An IDE and sources are my all.