# Parse a string containing code, return a Type

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I want to parse a piece of scala code, contained in a `String` and get the resulting [`reflect.runtime.universe.Type`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types) of that expression (`String => Type`). I've tried:

```
scala> import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain

scala> new IMain().exprTyper.parse("scala.Option")
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res1: Option[List[_2.repl.global.Tree]] forSome { val _2: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain#exprTyper.type } = Some(List(scala.Option))

scala> .get.head
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res2: _2.repl.global.Tree forSome { val _2: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain#exprTyper.type } = scala.Option

scala> .tpe
res3: _2.type#repl.global.Type = null

scala> new IMain().runtimeTypeOfTerm("scala.Option")
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res5: _74.global.Type forSome { val _74: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain } = <notype>

scala> new IMain().typeOfTerm("scala.Option")
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
res6: _75.global.Type forSome { val _75: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain } = <notype>
```

Is it possible, and if so, how do you do it? Thanks.

**UPD:** I have expressed the actual intent and where I am right now in this question: [Getting type information inside scala repl via IMain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678616/getting-type-information-inside-scala-repl-via-imain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after lurking around the SO (specifically thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11394410/163423)), I converged to the following result:

```
scala> def toType(expr: String): Type = {
     | import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
     | import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => m}
     | val tb = m.mkToolBox()
     | val exp = tb.parse(expr.trim)
     | tb.typeCheck(exp).tpe
     | }
toType: (expr: String)reflect.runtime.universe.Type

scala> toType("Option")
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Option.type

scala> toType("List")
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = scala.collection.immutable.List.type
```

Comment: I think what you've actually got in your two examples is the singleton types of the companion objects of `Option` and `List` ... is that what you intended?

Comment: @MilesSabin the idea is to make kind-calculator by Eugene Yokota (https://gist.github.com/eed3si9n/3610635) work as a command in scala repl. Turns out, scala repl passes `String`s to it's commands. Here's where I am so far: https://github.com/folone/scala/commit/fa0cdc29708de321f61bbb789a155ba94fc269d2
Seems to be working for types, available for scala at compile time (`Option`, `List`). I've not yet figured out a way to make it see types on the repl's classpath (e.g. it does not see types from scalaz, though repl is able to import them).

Comment: @MilesSabin So, back to your question, I believe, working with companion object's types is what intended by Eugene in his implementation.