# Getting type information inside scala repl via IMain

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

### Intent

I am [trying to add](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scala-internals/DdSg-qxOvyo) support for `:kind` command to [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) repl. Thanks to Eugene Burmako, I was able to get a [working prototype](https://gist.github.com/folone/5261743). Though it only works with fully qualified names and fails to resolve imported names.

I am now trying to use [`IMain.exprTyper`](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/index.html#scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain) to do the job, as it is aware of types, imported into the repl. But there is a problem. Everything I've tried returns a [`ClassInfoType`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Types%24ClassInfoType) like the following (displayed with [`showRaw`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.api.Printers)):

```
ClassInfoType(List(TypeRef(TypeRef(TypeRef(TypeRef(NoPrefix(), package <root>, List()), package java, List()), package lang, List()), class Object, List()), TypeRef(TypeRef(TypeRef(NoPrefix(), package <root>, List()), package scala, List()), trait Serializable, List())), Scope{
  def <init>(): Option.type;
  implicit def option2Iterable(xo: Option): Iterable;
  def apply(x: Object): Option;
  def empty(): Option;
  private def readResolve(): Object
}, object Option)
```

While the working implementation returns specific `Type`:

```
PolyType(List(TypeName("A")), ClassInfoType(List(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), TypeName("AnyRef"), List()), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Product, List()), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Serializable, List())), Scope(nme.CONSTRUCTOR, TermName("isEmpty"), TermName("isDefined"), TermName("get"), TermName("getOrElse"), TermName("orNull"), TermName("map"), TermName("fold"), TermName("flatMap"), TermName("flatten"), TermName("filter"), TermName("filterNot"), TermName("nonEmpty"), TermName("withFilter"), TypeName("WithFilter"), TermName("contains"), TermName("exists"), TermName("forall"), TermName("foreach"), TermName("collect"), TermName("orElse"), TermName("iterator"), TermName("toList"), TermName("toRight"), TermName("toLeft")), scala.Option))
```

### Question

I feel like I'm really close. Here's a playground, you can use to try everything yourself:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-20130328-093148-47645c7e7e (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain

scala> val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader) // Working approach
mirror: reflect.runtime.universe.Mirror = JavaMirror with scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader@3d34ec98 of type class scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$TranslatingClassLoader with classpath [<unknown>] and parent being scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader@5d990e8c of type class scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader with classpath [file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/resources.jar,file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar,file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar,file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/jce.jar,file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/charsets.jar,file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/lib/rhino.jar,file:/home/folone/workspace/scala-myfork/build/pack/lib/jline.jar,file:/home/folone/workspace/scala-myfork...

scala> val typer = new IMain().exprTyper // Not working approach
typer: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain#exprTyper.type = scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$exprTyper$@68c181f0

scala> val expr = "scala.Option"
expr: String = scala.Option

scala> showRaw(mirror.staticClass(expr).toType.typeSymbol.typeSignature) // Correct signature
res6: String = PolyType(List(TypeName("A")), ClassInfoType(List(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), TypeName("AnyRef"), List()), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Product, List()), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Serializable, List())), Scope(nme.CONSTRUCTOR, TermName("isEmpty"), TermName("isDefined"), TermName("get"), TermName("getOrElse"), TermName("orNull"), TermName("map"), TermName("fold"), TermName("flatMap"), TermName("flatten"), TermName("filter"), TermName("filterNot"), TermName("nonEmpty"), TermName("withFilter"), TypeName("WithFilter"), TermName("contains"), TermName("exists"), TermName("forall"), TermName("foreach"), TermName("collect"), TermName("orElse"), TermName("iterator"), TermName("toList"), TermName("toRight"), TermName("toLeft")), scala.Option))

scala> showRaw(typer.typeOfExpression(expr).typeSymbol.typeSignature) // Wrong signature
res7: String = 
ClassInfoType(List(TypeRef(TypeRef(TypeRef(TypeRef(NoPrefix(), package <root>, List()), package java, List()), package lang, List()), class Object, List()), TypeRef(TypeRef(TypeRef(NoPrefix(), package <root>, List()), package scala, List()), trait Serializable, List())), Scope{
  def <init>(): Option.type;
  implicit def option2Iterable(xo: Option): Iterable;
  def apply(x: Object): Option;
  def empty(): Option;
  private def readResolve(): Object
}, object Option)
```

How do I transform `ClassInfoType` into a valid `Type` containing the needed info? Alternatively, how do I get the `Type` using `IMain` in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? I'm using power mode which gives you access to the global from the currently running REPL, which is a shade more convenient than creating a new `IMain`.

```
scala> :power
Already in power mode.

scala> val g = global
g: $r.intp.global.type = <global>

scala> val context = g.analyzer.rootContext(NoCompilationUnit)
context: g.analyzer.Context = Context(<root>@EmptyTree unit=NoCompilationUnit scope=997093283 errors=false, reportErrors=true, throwErrors=false)

// aware imports of scala._, etc.
scala> val sym = context.lookupSymbol("Option": TypeName, _ => true).symbol
sym: g.analyzer.global.Symbol = class Option

scala> sym.tpeHK.typeParams
res21: List[g.analyzer.global.Symbol] = List(type A)
```

See also:

```
scala> intp.symbolOfType("Foo")
res26: $r.intp.global.Symbol = class Foo
```

But I'm not sure how to get at previously imported symbols:

```
scala> object Bar { class Bop }
defined object Bar

scala> import Bar.Bop
import Bar.Bop

scala> intp.symbolOfType("Bop")
res27: $r.intp.global.Symbol = <none>
```

**Edit:**

The reason OP's getting `ClassInfoType` instead of `PolyType` is due to phase. To get the same result as the power mode's `global`, one must set the phase to `typer`. To quote @retronym's explanation from [REPL: intp.global vs "global" available in :power mode](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-internals/fBLwvcjNGTc/9V-8kl7zue0J):

```
scala> :power
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP WHIR GYVE **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
    ^
    `----  this part is relevant
```

> Symbols have an list of types (aka `info`-s), indexed by compiler phase. (aka TypeHistory). Many compiler phases install `InfoTransformer`s to morph the type. See src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/transform/InfoTransform.scala for some documentation.
>
> To inspect the type as-at particular phase, you can use methods like 'exitingTyper`.

```
scala> exitingPostErasure($intp.global.rootMirror.staticClass("scala.Option").typeSignature).getClass
res6: Class[_ <: $intp.global.Type] = class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassInfoType

scala> exitingTyper($intp.global.rootMirror.staticClass("scala.Option").typeSignature).getClass
res7: Class[_ <: $intp.global.Type] = class scala.reflect.internal.Types$PolyType
```

> Or, a little more conveniently in :power mode:

```
scala> :phase typer
Active phase is now: Typer

scala> global.rootMirror.staticClass("scala.Option").typeSignature.getClass
res16: Class[_ <: $r.global.Type] = class scala.reflect.internal.Types$PolyType

scala> :phase cleanup
Active phase is now: Cleanup

scala> global.rootMirror.staticClass("scala.Option").typeSignature.getClass
res17: Class[_ <: $r.global.Type] = class scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassInfoType
```

Comment: This looks pretty strange. I've tried in the actual code here https://github.com/folone/scala/blob/master/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/package.scala#L130-L169 but it did not work: still getting the `ClassInfoType` from the `typeSig` method. but when I copypasted it into the repl, it did (at least for the `Option`): https://gist.github.com/folone/46326582337d7fbaee51

Comment: Anyway, looks like I found a working solution by combining your advice with the previously partially working thing: https://github.com/folone/scala/commit/fe6720c00affc08b5e83e8c2cb1c81139521da4e Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I added key info about phase based on @retronym's answer on scala-internal.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the mirror from the `IMain`'s global:

```
scala> val imain = new IMain()
imain: scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain = scala

scala> val mirror = imain.global.rootMirror
mirror: imain.global.Mirror = compiler mirror
```

Comment: I just tried. `showRaw(mirror.staticClass("scala.Option").typeSignature)` still says it's `ClassInfoType`. And it is also not able to resolve `Option` (without the fully qualified name).