# Template taking an Option as param, called from Java Controller

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I've got a template that takes one param that is an Option:

```
@(overlappingDates: Option[List[Date]])
```

How do I render this template from a Java Controller?

I've tried:

```
return ok(template.render(scala.None$.MODULE$));
```

But this gives the following compile error:

```
[error]   required: Option<List<Date>>
[error]   found: None$
```

Comment: Notice the difference:scala> val x = scala.None
x: None.type = None

scala> val x: Option[Int] = scala.None
x: Option[Int] = None

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it one of these ways:

```
scala.Option.apply(null)
```

or

```
scala.Option.apply((List<Date>) null)
```

see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720044/2873727