# Creating Java object off Scala Case Class : Using None (Option)

Tags: java, scala, scala-option

I'm trying to create a new Java object based off a Scala case class. All seemed to be fine, including creating new objects within the first initialisation, until I needed to fill in attributes of type `Option[X]` (where `X` is some other type. It varies based on the parameter).

In cases where this attribute had a value I managed to get by using `Some.apply("value")` however I'm at a bit of a loss of what to use when no value exists. If this were a Scala object creation I would use `None`, however that doesn't seem to be an option with Java.

I've tried using `Option.apply(null)`, `scala.None` and `null` without success. How does one give a `None` value with a type matching `scala.Option<A>` in Java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997433/how-to-use-scala-none-from-java-code